# How to get value for radio button from sql server using ajax and represent to list radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need get value for radio button from sql server using ajax ,php and represent value in form contain radio here code ajax

```
    function getname()
    {
    var id=$("#idEmploye").val();    // get the id from textbox
    $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    dataType:"json",
    data:"id="+id,
    url:"page.php",   // url of php page where you are writing the query
    success:function(json)
    { 

    $("#gender").val(json.gender).prop('checked',true)

    }
    });

    }
```

code html here

```
<label >Gender</label>

<input name="gender" id="gender" type="radio"   value="Male" >Male</input>

<input name="gender" id="gender" type="radio"  value="Female">Female</input>
```

currently can show value in textbox not in radio button but I need show value in radio button any help

Very Thanks

Comment: I didn't get the `represent value in form contain radio here code ajax` part, but you have a double unique identifier `id="gender"`.

Comment: You mean set focus according to the server value?

Comment: yes Ranjith i need set value according to server

Comment: first of all you cannot have id='gender' for both of your radio button. If you are able to see the value in textbox then you can use [$("#gender").val(json.gender).attr('checked','checked')]

Comment: improve code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("input:radio[name='gender'][value='"+ json.gender +"']").attr('checked', true);
```

or

```
$("input:radio[name='gender'][value='"+ json.gender +"']").prop('checked', true);
```

Then each `input` elements of `id` should be unique. Please remove the repetitive `id` . Use `name` property behalf of `id`

Answer (score 0):

Basically two html elements should not have same id.  So change your HTML like

```
<label >Gender</label>

<input name="gender" id="Male" type="radio"   value="Male" >Male</input>

<input name="gender" id="Female" type="radio"  value="Female">Female</input>
```

The you can set the value with js

```
var gender = element = document.getElementById(json.gender);

gender.prop('checked');
```

If you are using an older jquery version (< 1.6)

```
gender.attr('checked');
```